# Sharepoint Online: Delete version history in bulk?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm administering our organization Sharepoint Online right now and the storage is running low. I noticed that there are files that are taking up a lot of space because of version history (Example is a powerpoint slide with videos in it) It takes up to over a gb of file sometimes. I manually deleted version history of some files and it freed up almost 50gb worth of storage

Is there a built in way to do this in bulk? Or is there a built-in tool in sharepoint (something like the 'Storage Metrics') that traverses all files and shows the size but also shows the size with the version history size

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no built-in tool to show the size of version histories. And there is no built-in way to delete version histories in bulk.

As a workaround, you could delete version histories in bulk by using PowerShell.

References:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-online-delete-version-history-using-powershell.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/870e2f03-abf3-44b8-a2b6-71cb2aade2ef/powershell-script-to-delete-older-versions-of-documents-in-a-sharepoint-online-library?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

As Emily mentioned, there is no native function for bulk delete history in SharePoint. SharePoint allows you to delete versions only for a single selected document.

There are generally two approaches to solve this issue: PowerShell Script and a 3rd party tool. Scripts from "sharepointdiary" look good and can be helpful.

There is a tool DMS Shuttle for SharePoint. It provides an UI and can delete versions in bulk for a particular document, for all documents in a Library or sub-folder or even for the whole site.

The tool allows you to specify the number of latest versions to keep.
It is commercial, but there is a trial version and for students it is free. Disclaimer: I work for the vendor.
Take a look on this article: https://dms-shuttle.com/documentation/delete-version-history-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/